# DEPRECATION: ComputedProperty.cacheable() when upgrading to ember 1.10

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I recently upgraded ember 1.9 to 1.10 and get this:

DEPRECATION: ComputedProperty.cacheable() is deprecated. All computed properties are cacheable by default.
however I don't see any uses of this in my code. I'm in an ember cli 0.12.0 project

bower

```
{
  "name": "proj",
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "^1.11.1",
    "ember": "1.10.0",
    "ember-data": "1.0.0-beta.12",
    "ember-resolver": "~0.1.11",
    "loader.js": "ember-cli/loader.js#1.0.1",
    "ember-cli-shims": "ember-cli/ember-cli-shims#0.0.3",
    "ember-cli-test-loader": "rwjblue/ember-cli-test-loader#0.0.4",
    "ember-load-initializers": "ember-cli/ember-load-initializers#0.0.2",
    "ember-qunit": "0.1.8",
    "ember-qunit-notifications": "0.0.4",
    "qunit": "~1.15.0"
  }
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
 DEPRECATION: ComputedProperty.cacheable() is deprecated. All computed properties are cacheable by default.
        at Descriptor.ComputedPropertyPrototype.cacheable (http://localhost:4201/assets/vendor.js:21101:13)
        at http://localhost:4201/assets/vendor.js:73759:10
        at requireModule (http://localhost:4201/assets/vendor.js:64433:29)
        at reify (http://localhost:4201/assets/vendor.js:64404:22)
        at requireModule (http://localhost:4201/assets/vendor.js:64432:17)
        at reify (http://localhost:4201/assets/vendor.js:64404:22)
        at requireModule (http://localhost:4201/assets/vendor.js:64432:17)
        at http://localhost:4201/assets/vendor.js:77306:14
        at http://localhost:4201/assets/vendor.js:77307:4
```

seems to print the dep when this line runs at the ember data loading..

reified = reify(mod.deps, name, seen[name]); at 64432

[image]

Comment: What do you see at the call at the `at requireModule (http://localhost:4201/assets/vendor.js:64349:17)` line in `vendor.js`?

Comment: sorry what line? @Oren I changed the stacktrace

Comment: I see this:    reified = reify(mod.deps, name, seen[name]); at 64432

Comment: Can you run the ember inspector and put a break point on that line --  you should be able to deduce the dependency that is being loaded from the values of those variables.

Comment: the ember inspector doesn't run when hitting the breakpoint, that point gets hit many times. I think it print the dep when ember-data loads

Comment: It's probably Ember Data itself using the cacheable property, hop up to version 1.0 beta 14.1 and it'll probably go away

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Moving to both bower and package

```
"ember-data": "1.0.0-beta.14.1"
```

fixes this issue